# Query Twilio debugger logs via REST Api

Tags: c#, rest, api, twilio

We are having problems with numerous incoming calls failing in our app. I'm working on creating a "Failed Calls" report for our app but I'm not getting the data that I want.

Currently (I'm using version 3.4.1.0 of the `Twilio` `Rest` `Api` for `C#`) I'm trying to call the `TwilioRestClient.ListCalls` method, but it's only returning calls that have had a `CallResource` object created. That's not what I want.

On the `Twilio` site, under the debugger/overview page, I see numerous errors for incoming calls, but none of them show up in the *.`ListCalls` method call.

So, how can I query the debugger logs via `REST` `api` so I can display my own report in our app?

Here's an example of what I'm doing currently...

```
        var failedCallsRequest = new CallListRequest
        {
            Status = "failed",
            StartTime = from,
            StartTimeComparison = ComparisonType.GreaterThanOrEqualTo,
            Count = _pageCount
        };

        var failedList = _client.ListCalls(failedCallsRequest).Calls.Where(c => c.Direction == "inbound").ToList();
```

Comment: I think you might be looking for the [Monitor API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/monitor-alert) that allows you to list and fetch alerts that respond to errors and warnings that you would see in the console debugger.